# Cast an int16_t variable to uint8_t for passing to function

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I would like to pass a 2 byte signed integer to a function (STM32 USB transmit) that takes in a pointer to a 1 byte unsigned integer and the size in bytes, as such.

```
int16_t some_number;
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
```

I have tried to cast the number when calling the function but it does not work.

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)some_number,sizeof(some_number));
```

And I have also tried to split the data into arrays but the data that is received by the function is garbled.
I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: `(uint8_t*)&some_number`

Comment: You might want to check out the basics of pointers in your favourite C book. And also endianess.

Comment: tstting, In `((uint8_t*)&some_number)[0]` might be the most signifcant byte or the least.  Its up to the implemenation.

Comment: To do this correctly, you need to understand the specification/semantics of `CDC_Transmit_FS`. It is going to transmit bytes to some receiver. If you give it bytes to transmit and the receiver is going to expect the bytes in the same order you sent them, then you can just call it with `CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) &some_number, sizeof some_number)` (the extra parentheses you have do nothing except add visual clutter)…

Comment: … However, some communication protocols specify that the most significant byte should be first (called *big endian order*). In that case, you need to ensure that you send the bytes in that order, either by ensuring that `int16_t1 is natively big-endian in your C implementation or by using code to convert it to big-endian order before sending it. There are commonly available routines for this, such as `htons` to convert from Host TO Network order for Shorts (16-bit unsigned int). (And then there is consideration of `int16_t` versus `uint16_t`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass the address of `some_number`, i.e.:

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)(&some_number),sizeof(some_number));
```

Comment: Are you sure that sends the bytes in the required order?

Comment: No, I'm not sure.